# Removing repeated characters with sed command

Tags: sed

How to remove repeated characters or symbols in a string

`some text\n\n\n some other text\n\n more text\n`

How can I make something like this using `sed` or another command?

`some text\n some other text\n more text\n`

I can remove `\n` like `sed s/\n//g` but this will remove all the characters.

Comment: Repeated characters, or specifically empty lines?

Comment: Every repeated character or some specific repeated character(s)? Regarding "I can remove `\n` like `sed s/\n//g`" - no, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```bash
sed '/^$/d' file > newfile
```

In GNU sed, you can use inline replacement with `-i` option:

```bash
sed -i '/^$/d' file
```

In MacOS, FreeBSD `sed` inline replacement can be done with

```bash
sed -i '' '/^$/d' file
sed -i.bak '/^$/d' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/DoNf7u):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s=$(echo -e "some text\n\n\n some other text\n\n more text\n")
sed '/^$/d' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
some text
 some other text
 more text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tr` if it supports squeezings.

```
$ echo -e 'ab\n\ncd' | tr --squeeze-repeats '\n'
ab
cd
```

Comment: `tr -s '\n'` is [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/tr.html) and should be supported on most platforms.

Comment: @dawg Yes, short options are even supported by BusyBox (not long options though). I chose the long one for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following `[input]` or a file that is similar:

```
printf "some text\n\n\n some other text\n\n more text\n" | [ one of the pipes below... ]
```

Any of these work:

```
[input] | sed -n '/[^[:space:]]/p'
```

Or:

```
[input] | sed '/^$/d'
```

Or, if you want to filter `^[spaces or tabs]\n` also:

```
[input] | sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d'
```

Or with `awk`:

```
[input] | awk 'NF'
```